# How to make gtk button execute a terminal command when clicked using vala

Tags: gtk3

How do I make it so when a gtk button is clicked it executes a terminal command using gtk3 and vala?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to use the Posix package and `Posix.system("command")` which executes the *command* in shell so in this [Gtk.Button example](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Button.html) you'd need to add something like

```
button.clicked.connect (() => {
            Posix.system("ls");
        });
```

to run `ls`.

If you need to get output of the command, you can use [Glib.Process.spawn_command_line_sync](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Process.spawn_command_line_sync.html) which allows you to capture the output of the command and use it in your application.